# Change Grub default location for its variables

Tags: grub

I installed Manjaro Linux on a BTRFS partition and did not create a separate parition for "boot". I am dual-booting and I want Grub to remember my last selection. I followed the tutorial to do that, but then I began to to see "Sparse file not allowed" at booting. After some searching, it seems that this is because Grub cannot save settings when the partition is BTRFS.

This forum page ( https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-grub-btrfs-error-sparse-file-not-allowed/70031/4 ) has an accepted answer of disalbing saving last selection, but I want that. There was another answer saying "Change Grub default location for its variables from /boot/grub... to /boot/efi/EFI/Manjaro, for example (changes to Grub are necessary).", but he did not give any further details. How can I change the location to `/boot/efi/EFI/Manjaro`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the consequences of this method, but this is working for me with Ubuntu 22.04 with a root btrfs partition. I advise caution on this as it may lead to in inoperable system.

1. Copy grub into the ESP partition:

```bash
sudo cp -r /boot/grub /boot/efi/grub
```

2. Update `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` (this path will be different on Manjaro, look for the folder containing `grub.cfg`) to point to the ESP path.

With the existing config:

```
search.fs_uuid 1cc8a1e1-9d10-46e9-8e65-3b27047374a4 root 
set prefix=($root)'/@/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Update `search.fs_uuid` and `prefix`. `search.fs_uuid` should be the id of your ESP partition.

```
search.fs_uuid 5494-0F80 root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

3. Edit `/etc/fstab` and bind mount `/boot/efi/grub` to `/boot/grub`. You should already have an entry to mount `/boot/efi`.

```
UUID=5494-0F80  /boot/efi   vfat  umask=0077     0  1
/boot/efi/grub  /boot/grub  none  defaults,bind  0  0
```

4. Optionally remove/rename the old `/boot/grub` folder:

```bash
sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub-old
sudo mkdir /boot/grub
```

5. Bind bount `/boot/grub` from `/boot/efi/grub`:

```bash
sudo mount /boot/grub
```

6. Re-generate grub config. I used Grub Customizer for this step and enabled use previously booted entry.
7. Reboot